# Is it okay to set reduce_limit = false config in couchdb configuration?

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I am working on a map/reduce review and I always have reduce_overflow_error each time I run the view, if I set reduce_limit = false in couchdb configuration, it is working, I want to know if there is negative effect if I change this config setting? thank you

Answer (score 1):

The setting `reduce_limit=true` enforces CouchDB to control the size of reduced output on each step of reduction. If stringified JSON output of a reduction step has more than 200 chars **and** it‘s twice or more longer than input, CouchDB‘s query server throws an error. Both numbers, 2x and 200 chars, are hard-coded.

Since a reduce function runs inside SpiderMonkey instance(s) with only 64Mb RAM available, the limitation set by default looks somehow reasonable. Theoretically, reduce must fold, not blow up the data given.

However, in real life it‘s quite hard to fly under the limitation in all cases. You can not control number of chunks for a (re)reduction step. It means you can run into situation, when your output for a particular chunk is more than twice longer in chars, although other chunks reduced are much shorter. In this case even one uncomfortable chunk breaks entire reduction if reduce_limit is set.

So unsetting reduce_limit might be helpful, if your reducer can sometimes output more data, than it received.

Common case – unrolling arrays into objects. Imagine you receive list of arrays like `[[1,2,3...70], [5,6,7...], ...]` as input rows. You want to aggregate your list in a manner `{key0:(sum of 0th elts), key1:(sum of 1st elts)...}`.

If CouchDB decides to send you a chunk with 1 or 2 rows, you have an error. Reason is simple – object keys are also accounted calculating result length.

Possible (but very hard to achieve) negative effect is SpiderMonkey instance constantly restarting/falling on RAM overquota, when trying to process a reduction step or entire reduction. Restarting SM is CPU and RAM intensive and costs hundreds milliseconds in general.